# how to add image for all options in select Tag?

Tags: html, select

I am creating a drop down which will contains country flag for all countries listed in Drop down. Is it possible to show in each option.

Thanks.

```
<option> <i class="flag flag-us"></i> America </option>
```

Comment: No; `option` elements can contain only text.